# Replace words with stringi

Tags: r, nlp, stringi

I am trying to use stringi to replace certain words using `stri_replace`, however I have run into an issue when replacing similar parts of a word. In the example below I am fixing the misspellings of triangle, but it seems to be getting confused because 'tri' is part of 'trian' is part of 'triangle', and it comes out like 'trainglegle.' I'm not that familiar with `stri_replace`, is there some argument I am missing? Thanks for your help.

```
stri_replace_all_regex("The quick brown tri jumped over the lazy trian.",
      c("tri", "trian", "fox"), c("triangle",  "triangle", "bear"), 
         vectorize_all=FALSE)

## [1] "The quick brown trianglegle jumped over the lazy triangleglean."
```

Comment: Please remove bug from the title.  This is you not understanding regex not a bug.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to isolate words so that they are different. The `\\W` is non character. You can try something like that:

```
stri_replace_all_regex("The quick brown tri jumped over the lazy trian.",
                   paste0(c("trian", "tri",  "fox"), "(\\W)"), 
                   paste0(c("triangle","triangle", "bear"),"$1"),
                   vectorize_all = FALSE)
[1] "The quick brown triangle jumped over the lazy triangle."
```

Comment: This works pretty well, but for some reason when I try to replace "val" with "valuable" it picks up the word "oval" and turns it into "ovaluable" Code below:  stri_replace_all_regex("The quick brown oval jumped over the lazy trian.",
                        paste0(c("val", "trian",  "fox"), "(\\W)"), 
                        paste0(c("valuable","triangle", "bear"),"$1"),
                       vectorize_all = FALSE)
[1] "The quick brown ovaluable jumped over the lazy triangle."

Comment: You just have to do the same with words beginning : `stri_replace_all_regex("The quick brown oval jumped over the lazy trian.", paste0("(\\W)", c("val", "trian", "fox"), "(\\W)"), paste0("$1", c("valuable","triangle", "bear"),"$2"), vectorize_all = FALSE)` which produces `[1] "The quick brown oval jumped over the lazy triangle."`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want partial matches to be done then terminate some (or maybe even all your pattern arguments with a space (and also replace the space:

```
stri_replace_all_regex("The quick brown tri jumped over the lazy trian.",
  pattern=c("tri "), repl=c("triangle "), 
     vectorize_all=FALSE)

stri_replace_all_regex("The quick brown tri jumped over the lazy trian.",
       c("tri ", "trian", "fox "), c("triangle ",  "triangle", "bear "), 
          vectorize_all=TRUE)
[1] "The quick brown triangle jumped over the lazy trian."
[2] "The quick brown tri jumped over the lazy triangle."  
[3] "The quick brown tri jumped over the lazy trian."
```